# "ImportError: DLL load failed while importing cv2" but "Requirement already satisfied"

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda

I'm getting this error while trying to import the cv2 module on a anaconda virtual enviroment:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\anaconda3\envs\venv-1\lib\site-packages\cv2\__init__.py", line 181, in <module>
    bootstrap()
  File "C:\anaconda3\envs\venv-1\lib\site-packages\cv2\__init__.py", line 153, in bootstrap
    native_module = importlib.import_module("cv2")
  File "C:\anaconda3\envs\venv-1\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing cv2: Não foi possível encontrar o módulo especificado.
```

But the opencv-python is on the package list when I run `pip list`. And when I run `pip install opencv-python` I got this message:

```
Requirement already satisfied: opencv-python in c:\anaconda3\envs\venv-1\lib\site-packages (4.7.0.68)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.17.0 in c:\anaconda3\envs\venv-1\lib\site-packages (from opencv-python) (1.23.5)
```

.

When I try to import on the base environment, it works fine

Answer (score 0):

... reinstall the cv python package with this argument *--ignore-installed*.